# warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or '--ignore-removal'

Tags: git

I tried to add my files to staging on another branch in git. Basically I have done the following

1. `git checkout -b <newBranch>`
2. Modified some files in that new branch
3. git add .

But got the following warning (I have not found anything like this in SO and surprisingly on by googling. It is very surprising for me):

> warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or
>   '--ignore-removal', whose behaviour will change in Git 2.0 with
>   respect to paths you removed. Paths like
>   'thePathToFileIDeleted' that are removed from your working
>   tree are ignored with this version of Git.
>
> - 'git add --ignore-removal ', which is the current default,   ignores paths you removed from your working tree.
> - 'git add --all ' will let you also record the removals.
>
> Run 'git status' to check the paths you removed from your working
>   tree.

Does anyone know what does it mean and what should I do in the following situation? My `git version 1.8.3.2`

Comment: Likely the tough pace of progress is going to squash all us, happy git users :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is saying that you should use either `git add -A` or `git add --ignore-removal .`, because `git add .` will have a different behavior in the newer version of git. Since it says the current version will ignore deleted paths, my best guess is that the next version will default to including them.

It wants you to be explicit about what whether you want to stage deleted paths in the current directory.

If you want to add deleted paths, you should use `git add -A`.

If you do not want to add deleted paths, you should use `git add --ignore-removal .`

I think it is merely trying to warn you so that you will know that your command will do something unexpected (ie different from now) if you upgrade git, so you can take one of the above two options or just make a note of the coming change and move on, with the understanding that you are currently ignoring deleted paths.

Comment: Cool thank you. I actually came to similar conclusion. Can you just confirm that I have to use git add -A if I want to remove my 'removed file'? and by default the file will be still there? Because I actually can not see that file any more.

Comment: Yes, just based on your warning message, `git add -A` should "record the removals."

Comment: What is strange is that `'git add --ignore-removal <pathspec>', which is the current default` I have not selected anything, so it took default. But when I check on the disk - I can not find the file I deleted.

Comment: By the way, you should be using `git rm` to remove the files in the first place, rather than deleting them through other means. Then this doesn't come up at all, since you stage the files for deletion at the same time you delete them.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that when you delete a file by not using `git rm`, no matter which of the two options from the original question you use, if you 'check on the disk', the file remains deleted. The two options are only to specify whether you want to stage your deletion or not. Using `git add --ignore-removal` will not stage the delete, so if you want to stage it later, you will have to do `git rm`. While using `git add --all` will stage all additions, modifications, and deletions.

Comment: So, what, in practice is the practical difference between the 2 choices? If git hasn't "recorded" my file deletions because I chose `--ignore-removal`, what are the implications down the line?

Comment: To stage the deleted file, should we use git add filename or git rm filename? I'm talking about after the file has been deleted using some other means, like through sublime or your file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not really a big deal right now, because everything worked correct in my case (I was able to commit my stage, merge branches and push everything to the server with no problems).

The problem I encountered is because I deleted some file (I used similar procedure previously for a lot of time with the no warnings). Based from my understanding git is just telling me that the current format is already deprecated and will be changed in version 2. It looks like I have to use git add -A to actually remove my file from staging.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet same problem.
My context:

- A directory called `ABC` exists
- Delete the directory
- Create new symlink name `ABC` point to a `DEF` directory.
- Run `git status`. The problem occurs.

Solutions: Belong to your purpose.

- You can run one of that both commands.
- Or create new directory to backup `DEF` directory of the `ABC` symlink. So you can track them by git.