# How can I commit / remove a file starting by ":"?

Tags: git, gitlab, commit

Someone in my team pushed by mistake a file named ":w:w" (looks like he tried to edit a file with VIM) but now, we can't remove it in any way.

I tried with `git add \:w\:w` but when committing, git returns an error saying that no file matches 'w:w'

Is there a way to do so by command line, since we don't have any right on the repository?

Comment: You could `git reset` back to before the file was added,  remove it, and recreate the subsequent commit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use double `\`:

```
git add \\:w\\:w
```

Or

```
git add "\:w\:w"
```

Comment: If I try `\\:w\\:w`, I get the following: `warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or '--ignore-removal',
whose behaviour will change in Git 2.0 with respect to paths you removed.
Paths like ':w:w' that are
removed from your working tree are ignored with this version of Git.

* 'git add --ignore-removal <pathspec>', which is the current default,
  ignores paths you removed from your working tree.

* 'git add --all <pathspec>' will let you also record the removals.

Run 'git status' to check the paths you removed from your working tree.
`

Comment: I also stated that I tried with `\:w\:w`, git tells me that 'w:w' doesn't match any file

Comment: @Jaeger This is another thing, unrelated to the file's name. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027678/warning-you-ran-git-add-with-neither-a-all-or-ignore-removal) link.

Comment: Ok thank you, just adding 'git add -A' did the trick, I should have tried it earlier